# How to change text color using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want my quotes to be differently colored to quotes that aren't mine. Quotes that aren't mine I want to be black.

Hi, for an assignment I have to change a document to randomize the quotes displayed on it, add my own quotes, and to change their text color. I have tried to do it, but my quotes do not change color. Please help.

```
<html>

   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>My Web Page Of Wisdom</title> 
      <style type="text/css">
         .full-page { position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; }
         .x-center-y-center-column { display:flex; flex-direction:column; justify-content:center; align-items:center; }
         .quote { padding:0.5em; text-align:center; font-size:1.5rem; color:#336699; }
         .author { text-align:center; font-size:1rem; color:#a0a0a0; opacity:1.0; transition:all 1.0s; }
         .navigation-buttons { position:absolute; bottom:1.0em; }
      </style> 
   </head>
  <body onload="RenderQuote(0)">
      <section class="full-page x-center-y-center-column">
         <div id="quote-block" class="quote"></div>
         <div id="author-block" class="author"></div>
         <div class="navigation-buttons">

            <button onclick="OnNext()">></button>
         </div>            
      </section>
      <script>
         let CurrentQuoteIndex = 0;
         const Quotes = [
            { Text:"Apparently there is nothing that cannot happen today.", Author:"Mark Twain" },
            { Text:"The world's most famous and popular language is music.", Author:"Henri de Toulouse-Lautrec" },
            { Text:"Life is like riding a bicycle.<br>To keep your balance you must <b>keep moving</b>.", Author:"Albert Einstein" },
            { Text:"This is a quote.", Author: "Danny", color: "#ff0000" },
            { Text:"This is quote 2.", Author: "Danny", color: "#0000FF" },
            { Text:"This is quote 3.", Author: "Danny", color: "#FF7F50" }
         ]

         OnNext = () => {
            CurrentQuoteIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * Quotes.length ) + 1;
            RenderQuote(CurrentQuoteIndex);
         }
         RenderQuote = (QuoteIndex) => {

            let Quote = document.getElementById("quote-block");
            let Author = document.getElementById("author-block");
            Quote.innerHTML = Quotes[QuoteIndex].Text;
            Author.innerHTML = Quotes[QuoteIndex].Author;

             if( Quotes[QuoteIndex].color )
                 {
                     Quotes.style.color = Quotes[QuoteIndex].color;
                 }
             else 
             {
                 Quotes.style.color = "#000000";
             }
         }
      </script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you have created **Quote and Author** variables that these selected blocks id but in the **if** statement, you have assigned **Quotes** variable that it's an array and it doesn't have any relation with the **DOM**

However, for solving the problem, you have to use **Quote** in your **if** statement like below:

```
if (Quotes[QuoteIndex].color) {
    Quote.style.color = Quotes[QuoteIndex].color;
} else {
    Quote.style.color = "#000000";
}
```

I hope this answer will be useful.